# Receiving MMS in android and show it in my application as ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, mms

i am developing an application that should receive MMS from Specific Number.and 
and i found this code but it is give me a nothing,just hello world TextView

any Help will appriacte it

```
    package com.wzx.andapp.shh;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.text.MessageFormat;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.ContentResolver;
    import android.content.ContentValues;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class MmsReaderActivity extends Activity {
    private final Uri CONTENT_URI_PART = Uri.parse("content://mms/part"); // ²ÊÐÅ¸½¼þ±í

    private static final String MSG_ID_STR = "mid=%1$s";

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            long msg_id = this.getIntent().getLongExtra("msg_id", 0);
            // final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
            // final ViewGroup v = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
            // R.layout.mms_item_detail, null);
            setContentView(R.layout.mms_item_detail);

            ViewGroup listview = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.mmsdetaillist);
            // Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://mms/");
            // String selection = "_id = " + msg_id;
            // Cursor mcursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, selection,
            // null,
            // null);

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(CONTENT_URI_PART, null,
                            String.format(MSG_ID_STR, msg_id), null, null);

            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                            String partId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
                            String type = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ct"));
                            if ("text/plain".equals(type)) {
                                    String data = cursor.getString(cursor
                                                    .getColumnIndex("_data"));
                                    String body;
                                    if (data != null) {
                                            // implementation of this method below
                                            body = getMmsText(partId);
                                    } else {
                                            body = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("text"));
                                    }
                                    TextView t = new TextView(this);
                                    t.setText(body);
                                    listview.addView(t);
                            } else if ("image/jpeg".equals(type)
                                            || "image/bmp".equals(type) || "image/gif".equals(type)
                                            || "image/jpg".equals(type) || "image/png".equals(type)) {
                                    Bitmap bitmap = getMmsImage(partId);
                                    ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
                                    iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                                    listview.addView(iv);
                            }
                    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            cursor.close();

      }

       public void getAllMms() {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://mms/");
            String selection = null;// "_id = " + mmsId;
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, selection, null,
                            null);
            String[] temp = cursor.getColumnNames();
            for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++)
                    System.out.println(i + ":" + temp[i]);
            cursor.close();
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    // _id is the ID of the message. Captain obvious to the rescue? Not really.
    // This ID can be used to retrieve detailed information using either
    // content://sms or content://mms.
    // date no explanation needed.
    // thread_id is the ID of the conversation
    // body The content of the last SMS on this conversation.
    // If it's an MMS, even if it has a text part, this will be null.

    public void getSmsMms() {
            // usually, when you call query and want to return all columns you can
            // pass null as the projection parameter. However, you can not do that
            // with this provider, so that's why I'm using *
            ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
            final String[] projection = new String[] { "*" };
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations/");
            Cursor cursor = contentResolver
                            .query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
            String[] temp = cursor.getColumnNames();
            for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++)
                    System.out.println(i + ":" + temp);

    }

    public void getMms(String mmsId) {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://mms/");
            String selection = "_id = " + mmsId;
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, selection, null,
                            null);
    }

    public void getAllText(String mmsId) {
            String selectionPart = "mid=" + mmsId;
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://mms/part");
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, selectionPart,
                            null, null);
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                            String partId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
                            String type = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ct"));
                            if ("text/plain".equals(type)) {
                                    String data = cursor.getString(cursor
                                                    .getColumnIndex("_data"));
                                    String body;
                                    if (data != null) {
                                            // implementation of this method below
                                            body = getMmsText(partId);
                                    } else {
                                            body = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("text"));
                                    }
                            }
                    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }

    }

    public String getMmsText(String id) {
            Uri partURI = Uri.parse("content://mms/part/" + id);
            InputStream is = null;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            try {
                    is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(partURI);
                    if (is != null) {
                            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8");
                            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
                            String temp = reader.readLine();
                            while (temp != null) {
                                    sb.append(temp);
                                    temp = reader.readLine();
                            }
                    }
            } catch (IOException e) {
            } finally {
                    if (is != null) {
                            try {
                                    is.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                            }
                    }
            }
            return sb.toString();
    }

    public void getAllImg(String mmsId) {
            String selectionPart = "mid=" + mmsId;
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://mms/part");
            Cursor cPart = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, selectionPart,
                            null, null);
            if (cPart.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                            String partId = cPart.getString(cPart.getColumnIndex("_id"));
                            String type = cPart.getString(cPart.getColumnIndex("ct"));
                            if ("image/jpeg".equals(type) || "image/bmp".equals(type)
                                            || "image/gif".equals(type) || "image/jpg".equals(type)
                                            || "image/png".equals(type)) {
                                    Bitmap bitmap = getMmsImage(partId);
                            }
                    } while (cPart.moveToNext());
            }

    }

    public Bitmap getMmsImage(String _id) {
            Uri partURI = Uri.parse("content://mms/part/" + _id);
            InputStream is = null;
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            try {
                    is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(partURI);
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
            } catch (IOException e) {
            } finally {
                    if (is != null) {
                            try {
                                    is.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                            }
                    }
            }
            return bitmap;
    }

    public String getAddressNumber(int id) {
            String selectionAdd = new String("msg_id=" + id);
            String uriStr = MessageFormat.format("content://mms/{0}/addr", id);
            Uri uriAddress = Uri.parse(uriStr);
            Cursor cAdd = getContentResolver().query(uriAddress, null,
                            selectionAdd, null, null);
            String name = null;
            if (cAdd.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                            String number = cAdd.getString(cAdd.getColumnIndex("address"));
                            if (number != null) {
                                    try {
                                            Long.parseLong(number.replace("-", ""));
                                            name = number;
                                    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                                            if (name == null) {
                                                    name = number;
                                            }
                                    }
                            }
                    } while (cAdd.moveToNext());
            }
            if (cAdd != null) {
                    cAdd.close();
            }
            return name;
    }

    /**
     * Mark a single SMS/MMS message as being read or not.
     * 
     * @param context
     *            - The current context of this Activity.
     * @param messageID
     *            - The Message ID that we want to alter.
     * 
     * @return boolean - Returns true if the message was updated successfully.
     */
    public static boolean setMessageRead(Context context, long messageID,
                    boolean isViewed) {
            try {
                    if (messageID == 0) {
                            return false;
                    }
                    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
                    if (isViewed) {
                            contentValues.put("READ", 1);
                    } else {
                            contentValues.put("READ", 0);
                    }
                    String selection = null;
                    String[] selectionArgs = null;
                    context.getContentResolver().update(
                                    Uri.parse("content://mms/" + messageID), contentValues,
                                    selection, selectionArgs);
                    return true;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                    return false;
            }
    }

   }
```

Thanks in advance. I REALLY NEED HELP PLEASE

Comment: NO ANSWER! really Stack?

Comment: @SERPRO if they answer me, i will accept it :(

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21748209/receive-mms-messages-in-android-kitkat

Answer (score 2):

try changing the following line:
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(CONTENT_URI_PART, null, String.format(MSG_ID_STR, msg_id), null, null);

to:

Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null,
            null, null, null);